# equivalent spring constant for a drum floating in water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

If I have a drum floating in water, how do I find the equivalent spring constant?

I know that the water has density $\rho$, the drum has diameter $d$ and height $\ell$, and the positive direction is in the downward direction.  Therefore, the buoyancy pushing up on the barrel is my spring.

I have been reading the section of this topic in Mechanical Vibrations by Rao but there isn't any information that helps me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple harmonic motion, the restoring force is proportional to the displacement. So if you can compute the force $F$ on the drum when you displace it by a small distance $d$, then your "spring constant" $k = \frac{F}{x}$. I am sure you can compute that force (from the weight of the displaced fluid - Archimedes' principle).

But warning - before you can compute the frequency of oscillation, you need to account for the additional inertia of the system (which is actually very hard to compute for a drum - I know that for a fully submerged sphere it is equal to the mass of half the displaced fluid).

If you have trouble with the first part of this, I expect you are not expected to understand this second paragraph at all… but if you wanted to compute the motion of the barrel, it would really matter...

Comment: Let $m$ be the mass of the barrel, $A_i$ be the apparent immersed weight, and $\rho_w$ be the density of sea water.  By Archimedes principle, $\frac{1}{V_b\rho_w} = \frac{g}{mg - A_i}$.  How does this help?

Comment: Cross section A, depth d - assume this is where the barrel floats. Now increase depth by $\delta x$. Volume increases by $A \delta x$, and force by $\delta F = \rho g A \delta x$. So $\delta F / \delta x = …$

Comment: I think I understand.  Wouldnt it have been easier to just say by Hooke's Law, we have $F_s = kx$, and by Newton's 2nd Law, $m\ddot{x} = mg - \rho Vg$. Then for a differential change in depth, $V = A\delta x$.  Therefore, $F_s = k\delta x = \rho gA\delta x\Rightarrow k = \rho g A$.

Comment: Phrase it any way makes sense to you...

Comment: I found it more confusing when we were speaking of Archimedes principle when all I needed to do was equate the force of the spring to the force of buoyancy.

Comment: "force of buoyancy" (your phrase) == "weight of the displaced fluid (my phrase) == Archimedes… Well - I'm glad you got it now.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a homework problem, so I'll just give you a hint, rather than give you the whole answer.  The hint is that according to [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle), the [buoyant force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy) on a body that is fully or partially submerged in a fluid is equal to the weight of the [displaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(fluid)) fluid.  So the net force on the barrel at a given time is the weight of the amount of water that would fit into the volume of the barrel that's below the water's surface level, minus the volume that would be below the surface level if the barrel was at its equilibrium position.

Comment: I dont really understand your hint.

Comment: @dustin My third sentence was indeed rather lengthy and complicated, but do you at least understand the sentence that mentions Archimedes' principle?  If not, can you understand Archimedes' principle after reading the "Archimedes' principle" and "buoyancy" Wikipedia articles?